# How to redirect unattached image attachments

Tags: php

I'm currently redirecting all attachment images to their parent post with the following function:

```
function attachment_redirect() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_attachment() && isset( $post->post_parent ) && is_numeric( $post->post_parent ) && ( $post->post_parent != 0 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ), 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'attachment_redirect' );
```

How can I redirect all images that have been uploaded to the media library but remain 'unattached'? My aim is to redirect these images to the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts that aren't attached have no parent, and posts with no parent have a parent of 0.

So this:

```
if ( is_attachment() && isset( $post->post_parent ) && is_numeric( $post->post_parent ) && ( $post->post_parent != 0 ) ) {
```

becomes this:

```
if ( is_attachment() && ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) ) {
```